# Difficulty reading csv in java; using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I'm taking AP CompSci A, and we're working on a project with .csv files right now.

For now, I'm trying to parse/read a .csv file (containing hex codes for characters) in java, so that I can eventually write an applet to convert characters to their hex definition when prompted by the user.
Below, is the code that I'm trying to use to read the .csv file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;




public class showfont {


public static void main ( String [] args) {

    showfont obj = new showfont();
    obj.run();

}

public void run() {

    String csvFile = "/Users/rmollo/Desktop/entityfacts.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] answer = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            System.out.println("test [hex=  " + answer[2]
                    + " "
                    + ", description=" +answer[5] + "]");

}
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br !=null ) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
}
```

When I run this, I receive the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at showfont.run(showfont.java:37)
at showfont.main(showfont.java:20)
```

I'm sure that this is a terribly worded question (it's my first one), but If someone could explain to me what these errors mean/ how I can fix them, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Your exception means that there's a line that has less than 3 "cells".

Comment: You should really just Google the error in order to make an effort to understand what the error is, why it happens, and how you might fix it.

Comment: some array position doesn't exists. test your size array.

Answer (score 1):

Add this under your split:

```
if (answer.length < 6) { System.out.println("Line "+line+" is too short"); continue; }
```

and check if it prints anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the following line:

```
System.out.println("test [hex=  " + answer[2]
                + " "
                + ", description=" +answer[5] + "]");
```

Your indices are going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is this one (https://wush.net/svn/mindprod/com/mindprod/entities/entityfacts.csv), you have to skip commented lines where there are no commas

```
if(!line.startsWith("#")){

    //split code
    ...
```

Add more controls to skip "uncommon" lines.